# Laravel - Ajax error: xhr.send( options.hasContent && options.data || null );

Tags: json, ajax, laravel

When I refresh the document, sometimes is working fine (I get the json object in console), but many times I get 500 (Internal Server Error) and from jQuery I see the error is: xhr.send( options.hasContent && options.data || null ); Please help me. Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: '/ajax/cis',
        method: "GET", 
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
```

'/ajax/cis' is a laravel controller wich only returns a json object:

```
return response()->json(['cis_names'=>'cis_names']);
```

I also tried with post method:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/ajax/cis',
    method: "POST", 
    data:{_token: token},  
    //var token = Session::token()
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: I posted a new question, in same problem, but with more details.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39264332/laravel-dependent-select-boxes-with-ajax

Answer (score 0):

Try this with using Blade and see if that works:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/ajax/cis',
    method: "POST", 
    data:{_token: '{{csrf_token()}}'},  
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```